# Convergence in distribution with a sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ and $X_n, n \geq 1$ be random variables with cumulative distribution functions $F, F_n, n \geq 1$ such that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution.
Suppose that $c_n \rightarrow c$ and that $F$ is continuous at $c$. Show that $F_n(c_n) \rightarrow F(c)$

Since we only know that F is continuous at $c$, we know that $F_n(c) \rightarrow F(c)$, but I cannot figure out a bound for $|F_n(c_n) - F(c)|$ using just the information that $F$ is continuous at c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\delta >0$ be such that $|x-c| \leq \delta$ implies $|F(x)-F(c)| <\epsilon$. Let $n_0$ be such that $|c_n-c| <\delta/2$ for $n \geq n_0$. Choose  a continuity point  $y$ of $F$ in $(c+\delta/2, c+\delta)$. Then $F_n(c_n)\leq F_n(c+\delta/2)\leq F_n(y)<F(y)+\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.  Hence, $F_n(c_n)\leq F(c+\delta)+\epsilon<F(c)+2\epsilon$. I will let you prove, in a similar manner, that $F_n(c_n) >F(c)-2\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: How do you know that F has a continuity point in $(c+\delta/2, c+\delta)$?

Comment: Any CDF had at most countably many discontinuities. Since any open interval is uncountable, it must contain at least one point of continuity. @ptrax